# Do the operators + and • have to be different from each other in boolean algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove or disprove:

In boolean algebra the operators + and • have to be different from each other.

I thought that these two operator were defined axiomatically.
I know how to use boolean algebra for all sort of operations,
But I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: In the 1-element Boolean algebra they are the same, otherwise they are different. To see it, compare $0+1$ to $0\cdot 1$.

Comment: These are binary boolean operators, so you need two inputs. Show that there exists a pair of boolean expressions (inputs), where the outputs of $+$ and $\cdot$ are the same. Or, show that for all pairs of boolean expressions, the outputs of $+$ and $\cdot$ are different.